# Using curl to test Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, curl, routes

I have a model called users that I want to update using an API. The way I thought to do this is by creating an update route and plugging in code that does the updating. I created a test using RSpec and it seemed to work, however, I want to actually see the changed data in my database so I was trying to use curl to update my development database.

I tried the command

```
curl -X PUT -d "attribute1 = value1, attribute2 = value2" http://localhost:3000/users/1
```

but I got an error

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
<style>
.
.
.
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>
NoMethodError
in UsersController#update
</h1>
<pre>You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an    instance of ActiveRecord::Base. The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]</pre>
.
.
.
```

Heres's the relevant line in the routes.rb

```
resources :users, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
```

Here's the relevant code in the controller

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if params[:user][:attribute1] == ("x" || "y" || "z")
      params[:user][:attribute3] = Time.now
  end

  @user.update_attributes(:user)

  render :nothing => true
end
```

And finally here's the spec code that passed

```
describe "PUT 'update'" do
  before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
  end

  describe "success" do

      it "should be successful" do
          put :update, :id => @user, :user => { :attribute1 => "x", :attribute2 => "xyz"}
          response.should be_success
      end

      it "should update attribute" do
          old_attribute = @user.attribute3
          put :update, :id => @user, :user => { :attribute1 => "x", :attribute2 => "xyz"}
          @user.attribute3 != old_attribute
      end

  end
end
```

I tried to find a good curl tutorial to check my syntax but i could only find examples, so I'm not too sure if the syntax is right.

Answer (score 2):

your `PUT` data should look like this:

`user[attribute1]=value1&user[attribute2]=value2`

Similar to the way you'd construct parameters on the query string of a URL.

Comment: sorry - I just took a look at your controller code. Since you have `params[:user][:attribute1]` etc your attributes actually need to be wrapped in user[...]. Please see my updated response.

Answer (score 1):

When calling curl, you would have to send your attributes like this: user[name]=John&...
Did you do that?

Comment: No I didn't - That got rid of the error message but the user information did not get updated.

Comment: Also, you have to set the id without the user namespace, so id=15&user[name]=john&... In addition, it is possible, that rails does not receive the http verb correctly, try a post request with an additional parameter _method=put

Comment: So I tried 
`curl -X POST -d "_method=PUT&id=1&user[attr1]=val1&user[attr2]=val2" http://localhost:3000/users/1` 
but it still doesn't update. I also tried 
`curl H "X-HTTP-Method-Overrride: PUT" -X POST -d "id=1&user[attr1]=val1&user[attr2]=val2" http://localhost:3000/users/1` 
and that gave me an error saying there was no route for /users/1

Comment: Also wouldn't a PUT request to users/{id} do the same as saying id=1 in the data portion?