# Issue with PUT in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I'm working on creating a survey application where I create the survey on my rails server and as long as the user hasn't taken the survey the next time they open up my Android app they'll be displayed the survey to take. Once the user takes the survey I'd like to update the survey to contain that user so that they are no longer sent the same survey each time they log in. I'm using a HABTM relationship between users/surveys.

I'm able to get the survey/let the user take it/create the user choices back on the server but I'm struggling with updating the survey with the user that took just the survey. I'm pretty sure my problem is my PUT request (the auth_token is used to identify the user).

```
Started PUT "/api/v1/surveys/4?auth_token=8d707d9fa2b279f381eb416f1be887c0"
```

Here's my controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SurveysController < ApplicationController
      # before_action :restrict_access
      respond_to :json

      def survey
        @survey = Survey.check_survey params[:auth_token]
        redirect_to api_v1_survey_path(@survey)
      end

      def update
        @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
        @user = User.find_user_by_token params[:auth_token]
        complete_survey @survey, @user
      end
```

My model:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :surveytizations
  has_many :questions, :through => :surveytizations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, -> { uniq }

  def complete_survey (survey, user)
    survey.users << user
    survey.number_taken += 1
    if survey.number_taken == survey.survey_limit
      survey.survey_finished = true
    end
  end
```

In Using [curl to test Rails routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256830/using-curl-to-test-rails-routes) it goes into how to update an attribute of a user. I'm pretty new to curl - if I wanted to test updating an array of users with an additional user, how would I do that? I tried `survey[users]=user1` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is complete_survey statically invoked?

Comment: Yea - as soon as I hit the update action in the controller it invokes it. Not entirely sure that's the best way to do it though :)